# Error jquery background color

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código , pero me cambia el color del fondo del body, pienso que debe ser algo del scope, porque no me da ningún error.

Pensé en colocarle `body onLoad='setThemes();'`, pero me dice:

> ```
> setThemes is not defined at onload
> ```

Aclaro que el `.js` está separado del html, en cuanto a las demás funciones como `settings.darkTheme = true;` , si la realiza correctamente.

```
<select id="themes" class="form-control">

<option value="agar" selected>Agar Theme</option>
<option value="slow">SlowMotion Theme</option>
<option value="psyco">Psyco Theme</option>
<option value="ogar">Ogar Theme</option>

                  </select>

// Themes functions
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setThemes() {

        gg = document.getElementById('themes');
        g2 = gg.options[gg.selectedIndex].value;

        if (g2 == 'agar') {

            settings.darkTheme = false;
        } else if (g2 == 'psyco') {
            settings.darkTheme = true;

            $(function() {
                $("body").css('background-color', 'blue !important');
            });

        } else if (g2 == 'slow') {

        } else if (g2 == 'ogar') {

        }

    }
    $("#themes").on("change", setThemes);
});
```

Comment: lois6b , ahi está editado el post

Comment: settings, no afecta en nada es solo una variable y las cosas relacionadas con ella si funcionan , pienso que debe ser algo del scope porque todo lo relacionado con settings si funciona ya que está dentro del mismo js, pero ya el html va separado con el js

Comment: cambia blue !important a solo blue.

Answer (score 3):

Para cambiar el color de fondo del body te basta con hacer:

```
 $("body").css('background-color', 'blue');
```

Mira el ejemplo:

```js
var settings = {};

// Themes functions
$(document).ready(function() {
    function setThemes() {

        gg = document.getElementById('themes');
        g2 = gg.options[gg.selectedIndex].value;

        if (g2 == 'agar') {

            settings.darkTheme = false;
        } else if (g2 == 'psyco') {
            settings.darkTheme = true;

            $("body").css('background-color', 'blue');

        } else if (g2 == 'slow') {

        } else if (g2 == 'ogar') {

        }

    }
    $("#themes").on("change", setThemes);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="themes" class="form-control">

<option value="agar" selected>Agar Theme</option>
<option value="slow">SlowMotion Theme</option>
<option value="psyco">Psyco Theme</option>
<option value="ogar">Ogar Theme</option>

                  </select>
```